Extract PDF data in C# using OCR which include datatables
I have a PDF which contains tables and some headers and value field
I want to extract this data in c# objects using OCR, so that I  can use that to insert in database
The PDF data is in the form as shown in the images
I want to create an c# object example "Request/Slurry having value ABC"
and for table it should be an Array.
enter image description here


That specific pdf and PDFs that are exactly like it? Or PDFs in general?

I would recommend using services such as Azure Document Reader for a task such as this. They have SDK's in C# for this functionality, or you can use an http client here. PDF schema is pretty wild and you would not want to roll your own here.

I need a sample c# code to get this data in form of c# object. The PDF data is similar to the screenshots and I dont have Audio
